# How to add checked items in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
List<ListItem> checkedItemList = subjectCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                     .Where(c => c.Selected).ToList();

subjectGridView.DataSource = checkedItemList;  // causes exception
subjectGridView.DataBind();
```

I want to view the selected items in list view with subject ID and name. Items of grid view is `Model.Student` type. My code gives an exception. What should I do?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You are casting the items of the grid to `ListItem`, not `Model.Student`.

Comment: @LosMonas please will you give him an answer because I can see you have it in mind :)

Comment: If I don't cast into ListItem, c.Selected is not possible.i.e. it marks red

Comment: How are the `Model.Student` items added to `subjectCheckBoxList`? You need to have some collection of type `Model.Student` to add as data source for the `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

For the `GridView` data source, you need something that contains `Model.Student` items. If each `ListItem.Value` is of type `Model.Student`, you could use:

```
var checkedStudents = subjectCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(c => c.Selected)
                          .Select(c => (Model.Student)c.Value).ToList();

subjectGridView.DataSource = checkedStudents;
subjectGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkedItemList = subjectCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(c => c.Selected).ToList();
        List<Model.Subject> list = new List<Model.Subject>();
        foreach (ListItem item in checkedItemList)
        {               
                Model.Subject aSubject = new Model.Subject();
                aSubject.ID = int.Parse(item.Value);
                aSubject.SubjectName = item.Text;
                list.Add(aSubject);
        }            
        subjectGridView.DataSource = list;  
        subjectGridView.DataBind();
```